# How can you create a file inside a hadoop map-reduce job?

Tags: java, hadoop

I searched the web, but all I found was a site that claimed that it could be done. It didn't say how.

Comment: You want to create a file on the local file system of mapper/reducer ?

Comment: No, a bunch of files on HDFS, at most one per record in the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the FileSystem's API: [Click me](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html)
There is a method called "create()".

Comment: This looks like it might be what I'm looking for. Do you know how I would use this from the mapper in HDFS to create a file containing a string (for example, in the output directory in HDFS)?

Comment: You would initialize the FileSystem with: FileSystem.newInstance(YOURCONFIGURATION). Where YOURCONFIGURATION contains the namenodes IP mapped to the key "fs.default.name", then you can get the OutputStream and write to it.

Comment: At least you could use the configuration the job gave you through the context object. Then call create and write your String to the Stream.

Comment: FileSystem.newInstance(.) is protected. Is there a way around this?

Comment: What version of hadoop are you using?

Answer (score 3):

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
Path path = new Path("/my/path/file")
OutputStream os = fs.create(path)
// write to os
os.close()
```