# Need to Store mapper error in hdfs with the error values

Tags: mapreduce

Hello I need to throw an exception in  a mapper and print that error to a file in HDFS?

I don't want the entire job to fail. The mapper which has the error file should throw an exception and an error should be written to a file in HDFS.

How should I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

If you catch the exception in the mapper there should be no problem I think. In the catch code you can create a file HDFS. More information on writing data to HDFS can be found in this post discussing the `FileSystem` class: [link to storing files inside MRjob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722328/how-can-you-create-a-file-inside-a-hadoop-map-reduce-job)

Here is a link on exception handling in java as well: [Catching exception and continue processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798634/how-to-catch-exceptions-and-continue-the-processing-in-java)